# Difference between a regular and a non-regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Suppose $L_1$ is a regular language and $L_2$ a non-regular one, then:

is $L_1\setminus L_2$ REGULAR/NON REGULAR/BOTH OF THEM?

is $L_2\setminus L_1$ REGULAR/NON REGULAR/BOTH OF THEM?

Answer (score 1):

First, we know that, $L$ is a regular language if and only if its complement be  regular language.

On the other hand, $$L_1\setminus L_2=L_1\cap L_2^c.$$

Suppose $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, Let $L_1=\Sigma^*$ , and $L_2=\Sigma^*\setminus \{a^nb^n\}$, obviously, $L_2$ isn't regular, so

$$L_1\setminus L_2=\{a^nb^n\} $$
consequently, $L_1\setminus L_2$ can be a non-regular.

Let $L_1=\emptyset$, and $L_2$ be any non-regular language, so

$$L_1\setminus L_2=\emptyset$$

consequently, $L_1\setminus L_2$ can be regular.

for the second proposition, let $L_1=\emptyset$, and $L_2$ be a non-regular language, so $L_2\setminus L_1$ is non-regular, and if we set $L_1=\Sigma^*$, and $L_2$ be a non-regular language, then $L_2\setminus L_1=\emptyset$ that show us $L_2\setminus L_1$ can be regular.

**Note that, difference between two non-regular, regular languages can be regular or not.**

Answer (score 0):

Be $\Sigma$ an alphabet, consider $L_1=\Sigma^*$ and $L_2$ a non-regular language, then also its complement, i.e. $L_1\setminus L_2$, is non-regular (remember that the family of regular language is closed under complement). On the other hand, if $L_1=\varnothing$ (which is regular), then $L_1\setminus L_2$ is regular even if $L_2$ is not.

For $L_2\setminus L_1$, first consider $L_1=\Sigma^*$ and $L_2$ any (non-regular) language, then $L_2\setminus L_1$ is regular. On the other hand, if $L_1=\varnothing$ and $L_2$ is a non-regular language, then $L_2\setminus L_1$ is non-regular.

Answer (score -1):

$L_1 - L_2$ and $L_2 - L_1$ are both non regular since $L_2$ cannot be decided by finite automata. Intuitively, to know whether a string is in $L_2$ or not, we need something more powerful than a finite automata.