# If L is context free and R is regular then R – L must be context free?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, regular-expressions

Hi I am wondering if L is a CFL and R is RL then would the difference R - L be a context free language?

The difference might be the CF part of the language left then it would be, but I'm not sure how I could go about proving this without giving an example

Comment: maybe you can see this answer to a similar question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133055

Answer (score 1):

Context-free languages are not closed under complement. This is a fairly well-known result.